# Quick way to remove all folders titled CVS in a directory and it's subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, cvs

I have been using CVS and am having trouble when moving files from other projects. Is there a easy way to remove all folders [and subfolders] with the name 'CVS' so that i can add them correctly to my new cvs repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try to find them `find . -name CVS`, then remove them `find . -name CVS -delete`. If you'd like to ensure that only folders are removed, just add the `-type d` option to the find commands.

Another possible solution with more information during the search and deletion: `find . -type d -name CVS -exec rm -rv {} \;`

Comment: This is finding the correct folders but delete is not running because they are not empty. Can I override?
[EDIT: spelling]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `-r` flag for the `rm` command, just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`:

```
find . -iname "*cvs*" -delete
```

Comment: This deleted everything in the folder.